# Redirect standard error to null in Bash - "date: invalid date `Never'"

Tags: bash, date

I require the following error to be redirected to the /dev/null file.

```
a=$(date -d "Never" +%s)  > /dev/null 2>&1
date: invalid date `Never'
```

The date that is input to the date command is actually being passed through a variable which sometimes acquires "Never". In such a case, an error is shown as shown in the above message which is required to be suppressed.

Is there another method to redirect the output to the null file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing currently: redirecting the output of the **assignment** to `/dev/null`.

What you want to do: redirecting the *error output* of the `date` command to `/dev/null`

```
a=$(date -d "Never" +%s 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Send only `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
a=$(date -d "n" +%s 2>/dev/null)
```

test :

```
> a=$(date -d "now" +%s 2>/dev/null); echo $a
1429269352
> a=$(date -d "never" +%s 2>/dev/null); echo $a

>
```