# Redirecting stderr from Java execution in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm executing java code from bash as follows:

```
java Grade in > result
```

where *in* is a file in input and *result* stores the output. How can I redirect all error messages to */dev/null* (another file)?

Comment: How about `java your code 2>/dev/null 1>output_file`, let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect STDERR to null in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697410/redirect-stderr-to-null-in-bash)